# How can I include a .jar file as a resource in XCode, to be executed by NSTask?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macruby

I'm currently programming a Mac-native interface for CraftBukkit using MacRuby and XCode.

Right now, I am using NSTask and NSPipe to run Minecraft's Java server:

```
buk.setLaunchPath("/usr/bin/java")
buk.setArguments([
  "-Xmx1024M",
  "-Xincgc",
  "-jar",
  "#{NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource 'bukkit', :ofType => 'jar'}",
  "nogui"
])

buk.launch
```

However, I cannot add `bukkit.jar` as a Resource! It just won't build. I can include images easily, and `NSBundle` works.

`#{NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource 'bukkit', :ofType => 'jar'}` doesn't return anything (because the file does not include).

How can I include `bukkit.jar` as a Resource to be built into `sample.app/Contents/Resources`?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea but I wanna try it out when you have something that works! :)

Comment: Thanks! Progress has completely stalled because at heart I am a designer and have absolutely no head for Objective-C or MacRuby. Oh, well. If anyone can help, that would be super!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your jar file in the mainBundle under Resources/Java. To do that, adda a new copy files build phase of type "Java Resources", then drag and drop your jar file here.

Then call the method:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource 'bukkit', 
                         :ofType => 'jar', 
                    :inDirectory => "Java"
```

Notice that launching a separate process could be an issue in having your application accepted on the Mac App Store.